# Sending selected option with AJAX and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

i'm having a select-Dropdown and i want to send an selected option to ajax and then display it.

This is my HTML:

```
<label>Tag</label>
    <select id="day"></select>
    <label>Monat</label>
    <select id="month"></select>
    <label>Jahr</label>
    <select id="year"></select>
```

It's filled dynamically by JavaScript.

```
var day = document.getElementById('day');
var month = document.getElementById('month');
var year = document.getElementById('year');
var hour = document.getElementById('hours');
var minute = document.getElementById('minutes');

    var _month = ["Januar","Februar","März","April","Mai","Juni","August","September","Oktober","November","Dezember"];
    var _year = ["2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"];

    for(var i = 0; i <= 31; i++){
        day.options[day.options.length] = new Option(i+1, i + 'tag');
    }

    for(var i = 0; i <= _month.length; i++){
        month.options[month.options.length] = new Option(_month[i], i);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i <= _year.length; i++){
        year.options[year.options.length] = new Option(_year[i], i);
    }
```

It works fine. But how can i send an selected option with AJAX to display it anywhere ?

Comment: How do you like jQuery?? Can I use jQuery?

Comment: I would like to do this in javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery was created for us to use JavaScript easily.

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        tag = $('#day').val();
        monat = $('#month').val();
        jahr = $('#year').val();

        $.ajax({
          url: 'urlhere',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            tag: tag,
            monat: monat,
            jahr : jahr
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          beforeSend: function () {
                // things to do before success
          },
          success: function (data) {
                // results here
          }
        });
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/26L22c69/

Answer (score 0):

```
   var selctedDayIndex = document.getElementById("day").options["selectedIndex"]
var selctedMonthIndex = document.getElementById("month").options["selectedIndex"]
var selctedYearIndex = document.getElementById("year").options["selectedIndex"]

var dayValue = document.getElementById("day").options[selctedDayIndex].value
var monthValue = document.getElementById("month").options[selctedMonthIndex].value
var yearValue = document.getElementById("year").options[selctedYearIndex].value
```

Now you have value you can create an object which is easy way to access


{day: dayValue, month: monthValue, year: yearValue}

or how ever you want to read on the other side u can send in that way

For seding data in ajax:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance 
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/json-handler");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({day: dayValue, month: monthValue, year: yearValue}));
```

Comment: but how can i use it in the send-Method of ajax ?

xhttp.send("POST", "?","true");

Comment: Yeah as i mentioned in my last section of answer you can send using those method  

`var url = "URL";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Handler function for call back on state change.
 if(http.readyState == 4) {
  alert(http.responseText);
 }
}
http.send(parameters);`